# Restkit post with nested objects

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Hi I'm new to using restkit and I'm confused on how to post nested objects.  I am trying to post the following json:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "77777-795C-4374-9A29-5C12FF8031F7",
        "firstname:": "joe",
        "lastname": "bob"
    },
    "device": {
        "token": "phPS2sxbRRvoBbdE8e1VT8nFIJ4R8aJ6rdoCJ8iP1luWm3gUJDMnRHBs1SarfosTsIeYMMxwraLCY35B4whaFIISdosHzqa96vkZANHFy5rusHcrnUQuFgJHnsnqOsgxgOPd8QbrZAAxIlmqCt0an5pH69PWZAXcOVuzFilo310oeNW04qWZCWb8GWYMkODcMuUZANCAAFfvZB4ZAyokBADz"
    }
}
```

I am using Restkit version 0.20.3

This is what my mapping looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"id": @"id",
                                                      @"firstname": @"firstname",
                                                      @"lastname": @"lastname"
                                                      }];

RKObjectMapping *deviceMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[facebookMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"token": @"token"
                                                     }];

RKObjectMapping *authMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

[authMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
 relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user"
                      toKeyPath:@"user"
                    withMapping:userMapping]];

[authMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
 relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"device"
                      toKeyPath:@"device"
                    withMapping:deviceMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor *authDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:authMapping objectClass:[AuthCredentials class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:authDescriptor];

User *user = [[User alloc] init];
user.id = @"77777-795C-4374-9A29-5C12FF8031F7";
user.firstname = @"joe";
user.lastname = @"bob";

Device *device = [[Device alloc] init];
device.token = @"phPS2sxbRRvoBbdE8e1VT8nFIJ4R8aJ6rdoCJ8iP1luWm3gUJDMnRHBs1SarfosTsIeYMMxwraLCY35B4whaFIISdosHzqa96vkZANHFy5rusHcrnUQuFgJHnsnqOsgxgOPd8QbrZAAxIlmqCt0an5pH69PWZAXcOVuzFilo310oeNW04qWZCWb8GWYMkODcMuUZANCAAFfvZB4ZAyokBADz";

AuthCredentials *cred = [[AuthCredentials alloc] init];
cred.user = user;
cred.device = device;

[manager postObject:cred path:@"/testpost" parameters:nil
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {

 }
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

}];
```

My error message is the following:
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0x9427070 {DetailedErrors=(
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: 
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: error
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., keyPath=null}

Comment: What have you tried? Show your current mappings, request descriptor and posting method.

Comment: That's only one third of the information requested... Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Based on your mapping you will also need to give details of the object that you're posting (it needs to have the correct keys).

Comment: Your request mappings look ok. The error appears to be related to the response mapping where the server is returning an `error` and your response descriptor doesn't handle it. Turn on trace logging and use Charles to see what is sent and received.

Comment: Show your `postObject` method.  Also show how you develop your dictionary for the post.  Lastly include the response from the server.

Comment: @Petezah, have you solved it yet? I am experiencing exactly same issue